# How do I show/hide an element in YUI as in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, yui

In jQuery, when I want to show or hide something, I do this:

```
$('#elementId').show();
$('#elementId').hide();
```

How do I do this with YUI? I've tried YAHOO.util.Dom.get('elementId').hide(), asked my co-workers, looked at the documentation, and searched Google, and I've found nothing helpful. From the documentation, it looks like this should work

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.get('elementId').setStyle('display', 'none')
```

but of course it does not. All I can think of is this, which sucks because then I'm not using a framework:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can omit the Dom.get.

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('elementId', 'display', 'none');
```

FYI, in YUI 3 (as of 3.3.0pr3)

```
Y.one('#elementId').hide();
```

For YUI 3.2-

```
Y.one('#elementId').setStyle('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I have to do this:

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(YAHOO.util.Dom.get('elementId'), 'display', 'none');
```

Ridiculously and unnecessarily long, but it seems to work.